# Adding New Data Type(Module Object) In SugarCRM Module Builder

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I need to create new object type which need to be available in Module Builder while creating new and modifying existing modules.

It should be listed with "Person", "Basic" etc.

Comment: You can't create a custom data type, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: to create custom data type visit stackoveflow [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466681/how-to-create-new-custom-field-datatype-and-functionality-for-that-field-in-suga